# How to generate ngmodel dynmically in angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-routing, angular5

Here is the select list which is generated dynamically. I have 4 elements in `Dbarray`, so it creates 4 drop downs. It's working fine but when I change one drop down the rest of them change automatically due to the two way binding.

How can I prevent them from changing? How do I separate the `ngmodel` dynamically?

```
<div *ngFor="let abc in Dbarray; let i=index">
    <select name="srcColumns{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="dbserverService.sdb.sval" #{{i}}="ngModel">
        <option value="0" selected>Select Field</option>
        <option *ngFor="let tblC of tblColumn" value={{tblC.Column_Name}}>{{tblC.Column_Name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try using `Reactive Forms` instead of `Template Forms`? I suggest looking into that.

Comment: The problem is that you hard-coded the `ngModel` for each of them to the same value (`dbserverService.sdb.sval`). You will need to create a structure that has multiple values, one for each drop down.

Comment: I got your point @DanielWStrimpel .
But how can i achieve that?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details around what `dbserverService.sdb` looks like and how it is set up. Essentially, instead of having the `sval` property on that object be a single value, it needs to be an array the size of your `Dbarray` property on your component. Then your template would change to `[(ngModel)]="dbserverService.sdb.sval[i]"`.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I agree but how can i set the same variable in ts file becuase if i declare sbd.sval[]:any in ts file it gives me error.

Comment: You'll have to provide details around your `sdb` property on your `dbserverService`